# Multiple Headers Occur

Tags: html, mysql, css

This is supposed to be a simple high scores table. but everytime it pulls another player from the database it looks like this.

(table headers)

player

(table headers)

player

(table headers)

player

and so on you get the picture... I want it to just show the header one time at the top of the list of players... I had it working at one time and don't remember what I changed that caused it to do this, does anyone know how to fix it?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY explores DESC LIMIT 20;")  
or die(mysql_error());  
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
?>

<table class="reg-box" style="width: 600px; text-align: center;" align="center" cellspacing="5">
<tbody>
<tr> 
<th colspan="2">Trainer</th> 
<th colspan="2">Explores</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><?php echo "<a href=viewprofile.php?user=".$row['username'].">".$row['username']."</a>"; ?></td>
<td colspan="2"> <?php echo $row['explores']; ?></td>
</tr> 
</tbody>
</table>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code was the table is getting created in the loop, leading to the multiple headers.  Instead remove the creation of the table from the while loop and then try to update all the result set you get from the query you fired in a loop.  Try this.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY explores DESC LIMIT 20;")  
or die(mysql_error());  
?>
<table class="reg-box" style="width: 600px; text-align: center;" align="center" cellspacing="5">
<tbody>
<tr> 
<th colspan="2">Trainer</th> 
<th colspan="2">Explores</th>
</tr>
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><?php echo "<a href=viewprofile.php?user=".$row['username'].">".$row['username']."</a>"; ?></td>
<td colspan="2"> <?php echo $row['explores']; ?></td>
</tr> 
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow, it worked I thought I already tried that too XD well thank you for the help.

Comment: you are welcome.  If it solves your issue mark the answer to be correct

Comment: @nandu you should explain your answer so that it is a educational resource both for OP and everyone else.

Comment: @BillyMathews : Thanks Billy. will remember that